# Android Studio: How to add a TextView which continues last line of previous TextView?

Tags: android, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="This is an example of the first TextView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF SECOND TEXTVIEW"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The second TextView should continue the last line of the last TextView][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spx4i.png

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need it for different styling of text parts. Then you should use spans.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/

Answer (score 0):

Use a single TextView and use append function on it.
Example-

```
TextView text =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
text.append("Something here" + "Here too");
```